# Not compatible chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app, incompatibility

I have a very simple chrome app:

manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "App Name",
  "description": "Short description",
  "version": "0.4",

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },

  "icons": {
    "48": "/images/logo48.png",
    "64": "/images/logo64.png",
    "128": "/images/logo128.png",
    "256": "/images/logo256.png"
  }
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    window.open("https://google.com/");
});
```

This application is not supported on this computer. Installation has been disabled. The following problems are detected:
This app runs only on Chrome OS

[image]
Does anyone know what I have done wrong? I simply want my app to act as a shortcut to the website, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer with this [Transitioning from Chrome apps on Windows, Mac, and Linux](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/migration) documentation. Be noted that Chrome packaged and hosted apps will be discontinued on Windows, Mac, and Linux over the course of now and early 2018. It is also stated in this [Chromium Blog](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html).

> Starting in late 2016, newly-published Chrome apps will only be available to users on Chrome OS. Existing Chrome apps will remain accessible on all platforms, and developers can continue to update them.
>   In the second half of 2017, the Chrome Web Store will no longer show Chrome apps on Windows, Mac, and Linux, but will continue to surface extensions and themes. In early 2018, users on these platforms will no longer be able to load Chrome apps.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep, that covers it. Thanks :)